# Using POST to send data back to objective c

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

I am attempting to send data back to my objective c program from javascript.

I found a very helpful question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991360/passing-data-to-objective-c-with-post-rather-than-get) that got me started, but I quickly ran into a problem: the post seems to be failing.

I also verified syntax at [this helpful site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

I know this because I update the contents of a div on my page before and after the post call and I only see the update pre-post. I also have a breakpoint at the beginning of shouldStartLoadWithRequest and it's not firing.

Here's my simple javascript code:

```
function updateAction(obj) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="sending:"+obj;
    $.post("http://actionupdate", {"data":obj});
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="sent";
}
```

So.. my question: what am I missing? What's wrong with my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your syntax, I guess you are using jquery? The UIWebViewDelegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method does not seem to get called for ajax requests, which is what `$.post()` does. You have to use a normal post instead.

You may find [UIWebViewDelegate not monitoring XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353278) helpful.