# Using a custom NSURLProtocol with UIWebView and POST requests

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsurlprotocol

In my iOS app, I'm using a UIWebView and a custom protocol (with my own  NSURLProtocol implementation).  I've been fairly careful about making sure that whenever I load a url, I load something like this into my UIWebView:

myprotocol://myserver/mypath

and in my NSURLProtocol implementation, I take a mutable copy of the NSURLRequest, convert the URL to http: and send that to my server.

Everything works for HTTP GET requests.  The problem I encounter is with POST requests.  It seems like the UIWebView doesn't properly encode the form data in the HTTPBody if the request uses my custom protocol.

One work-around, since I'm using HTTPS for my server requests, is that I register my protocol handler to intercept http: instead of myprotocol: and I can convert all calls to https:  This other question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991360/passing-data-to-objective-c-with-post-rather-than-get), pointed me toward that solution:

But I'm wondering if there's any alternative and/or better way of accomplishing what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to use POST requests, one work around is to continue using GET requests for `myprotocol://` URLs, but transform them in your `NSURLProtocol` implementation to an `http://` *and* POST request to your server using the request query string as the body of the POST.

The worry with using GET requests to send large amounts of data is that somewhere along the request chain, the request line might get truncated. This appears to not be a problem, however, with locally-implemented protocols.

I wrote a short Cordova test app to experiment and I found that I was able to send through a little over 1 MiB of data without trouble to the HTTP request echoing service http://http-echo.jgate.de/

Here is my `startLoading` implementation:

```
- (void)startLoading {
    NSURL *url = [[self request] URL];
    NSString *query = [url query];
    // Create a copy of `url` without the query string.
    url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:@"http-echo.jgate.de" path:[url path]] autorelease];
    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [newRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[[self request] allHTTPHeaderFields]];
    [newRequest addValue:@"close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [newRequest addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [newRequest setHTTPBody:[query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:newRequest delegate:self];
    if (urlConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
}
```

I then implemented the `NSURLConnection` protocol methods to forward to the appropriate `NSURLProtocolClient` method, but building up the response data in the case of `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` (as is the case for responses from http://http-echo.jgate.de/).

Comment: Nice suggestion.  Sorry, I didn't notice your response, earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it looks like that `http:` and `https:` scheme requests are handled slightly differently than other (including custom) schemes by Foundation Framework. Obviously `HTTPBody` and `HTTPBodyStream` calls on relevant `NSURLRequest` returns always `nil` for former ones. This is decided already prior call of `[NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest]` therefore custom `NSURLProtocol` implementation has no way of influencing that (it is too late).

It seems that different `NSURLRequest` class is used for `http:` and `https:` than 'a default one'. Default GnuStep implementation of this class returns **always** `nil` from `HTTPBody` and `HTTPBodyStream` calls. Therefore particular implementations (e.g. one under PhoneGap, likely part of Foundation Framework) choose `NSURLRequest`-type of class based on scheme prior consulting that with `NSURLProtocol`. For custom schemes, you get `NSURLRequest` that returns `nil` for both `HTTPBody` and `HTTPBodyStream` which effectively disables use of POST method (and other methods with body) in custom URI scheme handler.

Maybe there is a way how to influence decision of which `NSURLRequest` class is actually used but it is currently unknown to me.

As a workaround, you can still use `http:` or `https:` scheme and decide in `[NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest]` based on other criteria (e.g. host name).