# MPMoviePlayer: is it possible to set a header to the streaming request?

Tags: ios, http-headers, streaming, mpmovieplayer

In one of my projects the server need a cookie(which I got from login request) to stream the video, but I did not find any way to associate a header to request in MPMoviePlayer/MPMoviePlayerController, does anyone know what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By registering a custom `NSURLProtocol` handler class, you can programmatically handle the requests made by the player.

For more reading, see [this post about NSURLProtocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274598/439096), [this article](http://codebycoffee.com/2012/01/08/decrypting-http-streaming-video-with-nsurlprotocol/), or [the Apple HLS doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-DontLinkElementID_8).